# Getting Score of user from Google Play Game Service?

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am new to Android App development. I want to retrieve user's score from Google Play Game service and i am using following code to get the high score but i do not have any knowledge how it returns the value and how to save it.

```
Games.Leaderboards.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(getApiClient(), getString(R.string.highscore), LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC);
```

Saving it to int or string does not worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method:

`loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore (GoogleApiClient apiClient, String leaderboardId, int span, int leaderboardCollection)`

returns

`PendingResult<Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult>`

Then you must use the `getScore()` method of the `Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult` class to get it.

Please see these links...

[The loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore method](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards.html#loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore%28com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29)

[The LoadPlayerScoreResult in the PendingResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/Leaderboards.LoadPlayerScoreResult.html)

EDIT: Here's how you can use it.

```
Games.Leaderboards.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore().setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LoadPlayerScoreResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onResult(LoadPlayerScoreResult arg0) {
                LeaderboardScore c = arg0.getScore();
            }

        });
```

This is how you get the score.

Comment: @SudeepAcharya Im going to place an edit, please see my sample code

Comment: @SudeepAcharya Add arguments to match the method signature: loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore (GoogleApiClient apiClient, String leaderboardId, int span, int leaderboardCollection)

Comment: @SudeepAcharya use c.getRawScore(), it will give you a value of type long. See this link for other ways to get the score: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/leaderboard/LeaderboardScore.html

Comment: You can also change the long to a string using .toString();

Comment: @SudeepAcharya You have to post the logcat so I can see the problem.

Answer (score 7):

The complete parameters for loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore is like below

```
     Games.Leaderboards.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(getApiClient(),
            getString(R.string.word_attack_leaderboard),
            LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME,
            LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<LoadPlayerScoreResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onResult(LoadPlayerScoreResult arg0) {
                    LeaderboardScore c = arg0.getScore();
                    long score = c.getRawScore();
                }
             }
```

R.string.word_attack_leaderboard is leaderboards id which get from google play game service

Answer (score 2):

4 years later I was having a similar problem with this situation. Some stuff has been deprecated and stuff no longer works. So for those of you who want to know how to do it now, in 2018... check this answer-

First you have to get the LeaderBoardClient with

```
mLeaderboardsClient = Games.getLeaderboardsClient(MainActivity.this, googleSignInAccount);
```

Next you can the score

```
mLeaderboardsClient.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard_id), LeaderboardVariant.TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME, LeaderboardVariant.COLLECTION_PUBLIC)
          .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<AnnotatedData<LeaderboardScore>>() {
              @Override
              public void onSuccess(AnnotatedData<LeaderboardScore> leaderboardScoreAnnotatedData) {
                  long score = 0L;
                  if (leaderboardScoreAnnotatedData != null) {
                      if (leaderboardScoreAnnotatedData.get() != null) {
                          score = leaderboardScoreAnnotatedData.get().getRawScore();
                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Long.toString(score), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          Log.d(TAG, "LeaderBoard: " + Long.toString(score));
                      } else {
                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "no data at .get()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          Log.d(TAG, "LeaderBoard: .get() is null");
                      }
                  } else {
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "no data...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      Log.d(TAG, "LeaderBoard: " + Long.toString(score));
                  }
              }
          })
          .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
              @Override
              public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  Log.d(TAG, "LeaderBoard: FAILURE");
              }
  });
```

The 3 parameters to **.loadCurrentPlayerLeaderboardScore** are as follows

> **ID of the leaderboard** to load the score from.
>
> **Time span** to retrieve data for. Valid values are TIME_SPAN_DAILY, TIME_SPAN_WEEKLY, or TIME_SPAN_ALL_TIME.
>
> **The leaderboard collection** to retrieve scores for. Valid values are either COLLECTION_PUBLIC or COLLECTION_SOCIAL.

Comment: Finally an answer not deprecated!